# pm2 'cluster' mode fail to load LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, node.js, gcc, pm2

i'm installing a npm package *ccap* to generate *CAPTCHA*. Because it's a c++ add on and requires *gcc 4.8 +*,i met some problems while installing it.

I compiled *gcc 4.9.4* and installed ccap successfully on my development machine.
However ,i met this wield problem when i try to start my application (without pm2).

```
Error: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/jwb/ccapDemo/node_modules/ccap/build/Release/hcaptha.node)
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Function._load (/home/jwb/ccapDemo/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:47:40)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jwb/ccapDemo/node_modules/ccap/lib/hcap.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

I googled a lot and got it fixed by setting  following linux enviroment variable in *.bash_profile*.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jwb/gcc-4.9.4/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Now it seems like working ,but when i try to start my demo in *PM2 cluster mode*,the same problem  occured.**

I also tried *pm2 fork mode*,and it worked just fine.

So i figured maybe *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* can not be found in *PM2 cluster mode*.Then i printed *process.env* and found *LD_LIBRARY_PATH*.

So i think this problem is somehow related to *PM2 cluster mode* ,but i don't know how to fix it. 
I do not have root authority and  can not just update */usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6* to a higher version. Have someone met same problem ?How should i solve it?

Software versions used

`OS         : Red Hat 6
gcc        : 4.9.4 (default gcc version is 4.4.7)
node.js    : 6.9.1
PM2        : 2.0.19`

Comment: I update my pm2 version from 2.1.6 to 2.2.3 accidentally a few minutes ago. And the problem is gone.

Comment: 3.0.4 same problem...

Comment: update pm2 version didn't  help？

Comment: Seems same problem in version 3.5.0